# Running BQ Load command using Google cloud scheduler

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to run bq load command once every day at 00:00 UTC. Can I use Google Cloud scheduler for scheduling this command?

Comment: Have you tried [scheduling queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries) in BQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel, there is no direct way to use cloud scheduler to execute-schedule queries, however there are options you can consider to run queries on schedule.

1. Use [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries) directly in BQ

   > Since your source is GCS, you can load data from GCS to BQ and then execute scheduled queries like mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#bq:%7E:text=%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20bq%20query%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%2D%2Duse_legacy_sql%3Dfalse%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%2D%2Ddestination_table%3Dmydataset.mytable%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%2D%2Ddisplay_name%3D%27My%20Scheduled%20Query%27%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%2D%2Dschedule%3D%27every%2024%20hours%27%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%2D%2Dreplace%3Dtrue%20%5C%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%27SELECT%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%201%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20FROM%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20mydataset.test%27)
2. Use scheduled Cloud Function to run queries
3. Schedule using [Data Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer)

You can also try what @Graham Polley has mentioned in this [blog](https://polleyg.dev/posts/bigquery-scheduler-cloud-build/), which requires an architecture combining Cloud Scheduler, Cloud Sourse Repositories and Cloud Build

Comment: Thank you Sakshi. Option 3 seems to be ruled out as my destination table name would change everyday. Option 1 - I would like to read from GCS and then load in Big Query, I don't see an option in scheduled queries. Option 2 - Can we run bq commands itself from Cloud functions or should I use any languages like NodeJS/Java

Comment: option1- updated answer, option 2- yeah you'll have to use client library python/java etc.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be able to do it directly with Cloud Scheduler you would need an intermediary like a Cloud Function to execute a command.  Alternatively you could try scheduling a data transfer, depending on the requirements of your load job.

Here is an example from the documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer#setting_up_a_cloud_storage_transfer

Based on your update of desiring to shard the table based on date, try scheduled queries in the following manner.

1. Create an external table pointed to the desired path in GCS as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#create_a_permanent_external_table)
2. Define your query, i recommend defining a query with column names and appropriate casting.

```
SELECT *
FROM myproject.dataset_id.external_table_name
-- INCLUDE FILTERING ON _FILE_NAME IF NEEDED LIKE FOLLOWING:
-- WHERE _FILE_NAME LIKE SOME_VALUE
```

3. Create Schedule Query with Run_Date Parmeter in the table name like new_table_{run_date}

Comment: Thank You Daniel. I tried setting up data transfer but looks like table needs to be pre-created for transfer. In my case,  table name would change daily table_<date>

Comment: If that is part of your requirement you should use scheduled queries as Sakshi mentioned.  Specifically either doing federated queries to access files in the storage bucket to then load into your date suffixed table, or loading into a stage table first.

Comment: ok. In scheduled queries, it is mentioned that only Google Standard SQL can be used. Is this ok ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes you described

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a file that is being loaded into Cloud Storage everyday before 7am, you may consider a more resilient design: when the file is created in CS create a notification that starts the process to load it. It is a better design that will get the information earlier into BigQuery and it will keep working even if the file creation is delayed.

When the file is created in Cloud Storage get a message in PubSub: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

Then, a Cloud Function is invoked that will execute the bq load command.

BTW if you have many files or even some dependencies, consider using Cloud Composer as an orchestrator to keep its complexity under control.

Comment: Thank you CarlesCF. Can I schedule a bq command to run as cloud function because I see only code runtimes like NodeJS, Python, Java etc.

Comment: You have to use some of the runtimes with its sdk to develop the code and execute the command. For instance for python: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest

Comment: If you want to process the information after it is loaded, then consider using something like Composer. Remember the Cloud Function is quite time limited.